# R: Pathfile created in variable is not readable although visually exactly the same as typed file path which works

Tags: r, file, path

I would like to create file paths to over 70 files. I am reading in csv-tables and am exporting png with the same name, so the file extension should be changeable.

I tried to create the path in different ways, as you can see in my code example, but in either way I get an error message:

> Error: "In file(file, "rt") : No such file or directory"

When I type the file directory in directly the file is found. Visually I can see no difference between the created file path and the typed file path. But when I compare them, there is a difference. Here is my code for better explanation:

These are one example ordner and one example filename

```
ordner <- "2017-11-05–2017-11-06_fog_far_inland"
filename <- "2017-11-05–2017-11-07_fog_far_inland_Station_11_CaletaLoa

type_1 <- ".csv"
type_2 <- ".png"
```

These are the two ways I tried to create my file path

```
csvname = paste(getwd(), ordner, filename, type_1, sep = "")
csvname <- file.path(getwd(), ordner, paste(filename,".csv",sep=""))
```

The following throws the error message:

> Error: "In file(file, "rt"): cant find file 'workingDirectory/2017-11-05–2017-11-06_fog_far_inland/2017-11-05–2017-11-07_fog_far_inland_Station_11_CaletaLoa.csv: No such file or directory"

```
datatable <- read.csv(csvname, header = T)
```

Copying the path from the error message in a second variable gives the same error message

```
csvname2 <- "workingDirectory/2017-11-05–2017-11-06_fog_far_inland/2017-11-05–2017-11-07_fog_far_inland_Station_11_CaletaLoa.csv"
datatable <- read.csv(csvname2, header = T)
```

Typing exactly the same in the variable manually works:

```
csvname3 <- "workingDirectory/2017-11-05–2017-11-06_fog_far_inland/2017-11-05–2017-11-07_fog_far_inland_Station_11_CaletaLoa.csv"
datatable <- read.csv(csvname3, header = T)
```

As there is visually no difference between the file paths I tested them in an if-statement comparing the created path file variable with the variable with the typed path file it saids "false".

```
if (csvname == csvname3){
  print("true")
} else {
  print("false")
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are many possibilities for this abnormal behaviour. Perhaps in your file path some characters are similar to each other but with different encodings. Perhaps some non-printable characters exist there. Use this code to identify the binary codes of those characters `setdiff(charToRaw(csvname), charToRaw(csvname3))`.

Comment: The output of this code is:
raw(0)
I am not sure, what it tells me.

Comment: That means every character in csvname is in csvname3. Then probably csvname3 has some non-printable characters in it. Try this `setdiff(charToRaw(csvname3), charToRaw(csvname))`.

Comment: Yes, now it sais not a single character in csvname is in csvname3.

Comment: Then the problem is that your system is using an encoding differing from R's default, which is UTF-8. Please have a look at `iconv`. If you want further help, please share the output from `sessionInfo()`.